# CSS/JS animation on scroll with scroll locked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to reproduce kind of this animation with HTML, CSS and javascript (jQuery too if needed). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTMjNVTK_DY

Basically, there are multiple svg or png layers with content and transparent area. When scrolling down, the layers look closer by animating the `transform:translateZ rotate;` property. 
Between layers, there are names.

Here's what I imagine the HTML to look like

```
<body>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
</body>
```

How can I animate those elements on scroll, without the window actually scrolling ? Do I absolutely need javascript ? Is there a library that would be relevant ?

Thank you.

Comment: It may be worth to take a look at [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/)

Comment: @Flying indeed that looks interesting. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to make the simpler as possible example, I hope it helps!

```
<style>
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    perspective: 500px;
}
#content {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#layer1,
#layer2,
#layer3,
#layer4 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 30px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
#layer1 {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
#layer2 {
    border-color: green;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, -300px);
}
#layer3 {
    border-color: blue;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, -600px);
}
#layer4 {
    border-color: black;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, -900px);
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="layer1"></div>
        <div id="layer2"></div>
        <div id="layer3"></div>
        <div id="layer4"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

let z = 0;

window.addEventListener("wheel", function (event) {
    z += event.deltaY;
    content.style.transform = "translate3d(0, 0, " + z + "px)";
    event.preventDefault();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's giving me a better understanding ! 
In your demo, when scrolling up, the squares become smaller and smaller. Is there a way to block their minimum size? or to block the scroll up from a certain point ?

Comment: Yes, you can easily limit the z values with a maximum and a minimum with javascript. Please think that I have given you an answer that is probably way out of the scope of stackoverflow, but I did in the hope that you can start working with it in the visual part, but it is not finished by any means. It will require way more work, if you need help with the Javascript part, please consider professional help.

Comment: Yes I know that, thank you very much ! I'll manage the javascript part just fine, it's the concept that I hadn't really grasped ;) thanks again for your help !

Comment: It would be nice to see the final result, please share it!

Comment: great idea, i'll edit my post with the final result when I'm done !